# How to shared const data with lib files (IAR .a)

Tags: c, lib, .a

I try to define const parameter in lib project (.a file in IAR) and initialize the parameter when compiled the application with the lib file
Define in lib project :

.icf file :

```
    define symbol ROM_Test_config_start__     =   0x00018000;
    define symbol ROM_Test_config_end__       =   0x00018FFF;

    
    define region TEMP_CONFIG_region = mem:[from ROM_Test_config_start__ to 
                                                                    ROM_factory_config_end__];

    place at start of TEMP_CONFIG_region {readonly  section .temp_Config_section };
```

Define in lib  .c file :

```
     __ro_placement  const uint8_t temp_Config[6]   @".temp_Config_section"     ;
```

Define in .lib  .h file (API h file ) :

```
     extern const uint8_t temp_Config[6];
```

Define in application project :

```
Define in .c application file : 

  extern const uint8_t temp_Config[6]= { 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,};
```

Linker result :

Error[Li006]: duplicate definitions for "temp_Config"; in "C:\Perforce\workspace\Y2_SDK_RFD_app\RF\PowerCode2\CC13xx_Platform_source\
application\SDK_application_project_SDK_app_CC1312\Debug\Obj\main.o", and "config.o(EcoSystem_SDK_Lib_CC1312R1_v00.00.a)"

Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Yaki

Comment: Your application .c file declares `temp_Config` again, just with a different initial value. If the intent is to set the library’s definition to that value, you need to do that in a function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.